# Spring-boot BindingResult not getting errors

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-data

My BindingResult is not getting the errors but they appear on the stack trace.

My sales has a regex pattern for salesno:

```
@Entity
public class Sale {

public Sale() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp = "^S\\d{9}$", message = "Sales number must be in the format S123456789")
private String salesno;
```

The DTO backing the html for uses SalesViewDTO

```
public class SaleViewModel {

private Sale sale = new Sale();
```

And the controller:

```
    @PostMapping("newSale")
public String saleSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("SaleViewModel") SaleViewModel saleViewModel, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        for(ObjectError error : errors) {
            System.out.println("This is the error: " +error);
        }
        return "sale";
    } else {
        // Other stuff
```

If I then try to submit the form I get the message on console:

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Sales number must be in the format S123456789', propertyPath=salesno, rootBeanClass=class com.gmbh.domain.Sale, messageTemplate='Sale number must be in the format S123456789'}
```

I want to know why the Binding Result result  is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add @Valid to the sale inner object of the SaleViewModel

```
public class SaleViewModel {
    @Valid
    private Sale sale = new Sale();
```

It's necessary to validate nested objects as well.

Comment: if its too long I will post another question but how do you get hibernate @UniqueConstraint errors into bindingresult like : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '123456789'

Comment: It's not part of validation logic. Usually a custom annotation is introduced e.g. @UserNotExists where all the logic is checked http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/